# How to load different documents if the window.location.host property is equal to a specific value

Tags: javascript, html

I want a web page in my site to auto load a different document or execute a block of code if  `window.location.host == "subdomain.mywebsite.com"` and it should load a new document if        `window.location.host == "mywebsite.com"`.

I have tried using the if...else statement with logical operators but it seems it not working, this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
  var ATurl=window.location.host;
  document.write(ATurl);
  if(ATurl == downloads.wping.tk) {
    document.write("--an html function to execute here--");
  )
  else {
    document.write("--another html function to execute here!--");
  }
 </script>
</html>
```

can someone help me out with the code. Perhaps am wrong somewhere! Thanks

Comment: You have a syntax error in your if statement you're using a parenthesis `)` where the it could be brace `}` to close the if before the else. This why it's important to format your code properly it would have been a lot easier to spot if it wasn't all one line.

Comment: in line 8, `)` shouild be a `}` dunno if its a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong in your code

- in line 8
  `)` should be replaced with a `}`
  to properly close the if statement
- in line 6

  `if(ATurl == downloads.wping.tk) {`
  You are trying to acces  `tk` a propertie of `wping` in `downloads`
  You want to compare `ATurl` against a String so put `"` around `downloads.wping.tk`

Then you should end up with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
  var ATurl= window.location.host;
  document.write(ATurl);
  if(ATurl == "downloads.wping.tk") {
    document.write("--an html function to execute here--");
  }
  else {
    document.write("--another html function to execute here!--");
  }
 </script>
</html>​
```

Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFPEh/) for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quote marks around your strings. Also, you closed the `if` with the wrong type of bracket (a parenthesis)

```
if (window.location.host == 'downloads.wping.tk') {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ...
  ) //SHOULD BE A } HERE
  else {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`downloads.wping.tk` doesn't do what you expect. Try this:

```
it( ATurl !== "mywebsite.com" ) {
    document.location = window.location.protocol + "://mywebsite.com/";
}
```

`document.write()` isn't necessary/doesn't make sense.

Also get used to look into the JavaScript console of your browser, it will tell you about any syntax errors in your code.